# Change text colour of focused item in DropdownMenuButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter

The focused item in the dropdown menu is highlighted in the accent/secondary colour from the theme ([example to show the highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kff5.png)). However, if the highlight colour is of a different brightness than the background, the text isn't easily visible (see previous example), so I'd like to change the text colour of just the focused item. I've tried setting `onSecondary` to a contrasting colour in the theme's `colorScheme`, but the text colour of the focused dropdown menu item is not automatically changed to it. `selectedItemBuilder` in `DropdownMenuButton` seems to affect the display when the menu is closed, not the selected item in the menu. Changing the text colour in the `DropdownMenuItem` by comparing it to the menu's current value (eg. `items: options.map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(value: e.value, child: Text(e.text, style: TextStyle(color: curr_value == e.value ? Colors.black : null)))).toList()`) is insufficient because the highlight is due to the item being *focused*, not due to it being the selected value ([this is what happens when I change the focused item using tab or arrow keys when I do that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZJqL.png)). I also tried looking through the `DropdownMenuButton` source code for clues, but I couldn't find where the highlight is applied. Is there a theme parameter that controls the highlighted option text colour?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution! You can use `Focus.of(context)` in the menu item widgets to check if they're focused. Here I have an example with a `builder` function being passed to a wrapper `Widget` that keeps track of the focus. Then, `focused` can be used in the builder to determine which text colour to use.

```dart
class OptionEntryItemWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  Widget Function(BuildContext, bool) builder;

  OptionEntryItemWrapper({required this.builder});

  @override
  _OptionEntryItemWrapper createState() => _OptionEntryItemWrapper();
}

class _OptionEntryItemWrapper extends State<OptionEntryItemWrapper> {
  bool focused = false;
  FocusNode? node;

  void focus_listener() {
    if (mounted && node != null)
      setState(() {
        focused = node!.hasFocus;
      });
    ;
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    node?.removeListener(focus_listener);
    node = Focus.of(context);
    node?.addListener(focus_listener);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    node?.removeListener(focus_listener);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.builder(context, focused);
  }
}
```

And in the `items:` of `DropdownButton`:

```dart
DropdownMenuItem(value: value, child: OptionEntryItemWrapper(builder: builder))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean variable. set it to false then make a onclicked Function with help of the gesture detection widget

```
Onclicked(){
var= true,
}
```

inside the icon style write a condition:

```
var?backgroud.Blue:backgroud.white
```

(P.S. I have only written the logic Its not in right Syntax)

Comment: For something like this to work I'd have to keep track of every key that changes the focused element, which is really too much of a hassle like implementing the dropdown myself.